# Can You Force a Dictionary To Return a Non Optional Or Assert?

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

is there a way to force dictionary to return a non optional value? , and if its doesn't exists just assert

```
var dic = Dictionary<String,String>()

dic["0"] = "Zero" 

let z = dic["0"] // is there a way that the 'z' variable will not be an optional (without doing an optional unwrapping, and so) , and if the value don't exists the program will assert
```

is that kind of thing is possible with an extension of dictionary ?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0217-bangbang.md)?

Comment: What's the problem with using `guard`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID72) `(a ?? b)`

```
var dic = Dictionary<String,String>()

dic["0"] = "Zero" 

let z = dic["0"] ?? "Any Default String"
```

z constant will be of type String.

A more common way to deal with optionals is using `if let` and `guard let`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom `Dictionary` `subscript` function in an `extension`.  You'll need to add a label to distinguish it from the normal `Dictionary` subscripting.

**Example:**

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(force key: Key) -> Value {
        if let value = self[key] {
            return value
        }
        fatalError("Forced key \(key) wasn't found in Dictionary")
    }
}

var dic = [String : String]()

dic["0"] = "Zero"

let z = dic[force: "0"]
print(z)
print(type(of: z))
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Zero
> String
> ```